# Does protein kinase A accelerate glycolysis or slow it down?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

In liver cells, the activity of PFK-1 is regulated by the PFK-2/FBP-2 complex, whose activity is in turn controlled by glucagon and insulin.

Glucagon activates protein kinase A.  Then protein kinase A phosphorylates the PFK-2/FBP-2 complex, so that the PFK-2/FBP-2 complex will make fructose-6P from fructose-2,6-bisP.  Since fructose-2,6-bisP activates PFK-1 (in liver cells), without it the process of glycolysis will slow down.

However I read from my notes that protein kinase A is dependent on cAMP (so that when the energy level is low, the increase in cAMP will cause protein kinase A to increase in activity).  It seems that protein kinase A should help increase glycolysis, so why does activating it by glucagon cause glycolysis to slow down instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **fallacy** in your argument, which is the parenthetical statement:

> so that when energy level is low, the increase in cAMP will cause protein kinase A to increase in activity

The activity of adenyl cyclase (the enzyme catalysing the production oc cAMP) is **not** controlled by energy charge, but by hormones such as glucagon. That is how glucagon has its effect on protein kinase A (better thought of as cyclic AMP-dependent protein kinase to remind you of this fact). That is why cAMP is known as a ‘second messenger’ — the hormone being ‘first messenger’ (and the enzyme that becomes phosphorylated being the recipient of the message). See, for example, [Figure 21.14 from Berg *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22429/bin/ch21f14.jpg)

Therefore the explanation in the [Wikipedia article on PFK2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphofructokinase_2) is quite self-consistent:

> When glucose level is low, glucagon is released into the bloodstream, triggering a cAMP signal cascade. In the liver Protein kinase A inactivates the PFK-2 domain of the bifunctional enzyme via phosphorylation, however this does not occur in skeletal muscle. The F-2,6-BPase domain is then activated which lowers fructose 2,6-bisphosphate (F-2,6-BP) levels. Because F-2,6-BP normally stimulates phosphofructokinase-1(PFK1), the decrease in its concentration **leads to the inhibition of glycolysis** and the stimulation of gluconeogenesis.[8]

So the answer to the question posed in your title is: **in liver cAMP causes the inhibition of glycolysis**.